# How to trigger a cron job after a controller action in ruby on rails.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I want to create a cron job to send mail every week after the user creation.

User controller

```
 def create
 @user = User.new(user_params)
 if @user.save
    redirect_to(@book, :notice => 'User created')
  else
    render 'new'
  end
  Mailer.send_mail(@user).deliver
  end
```

Scheduler.rb

```
      every :monday do
      runner "Mailers.send_mail.deliver"
      end
```

Mailers.rb

```
      def send_mail(user)
      @user = user
      mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'your account has been created')
     end
```

How to run the cron job after the user created?

Comment: whenever --update-crontab and pass an identifier that uniquely identifies your application for [more info](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I want to run the cron job only after the user created. My cron job run automatically with out considering whether a user created or not.

Comment: Do you want to send a reminder exactly 1 week after each single sign up? Or a dailay reminder to all users that sign up a week ago?

Comment: Weekly once to all the users that sign up a week ago.